# Corebluetooth NSMutableArray with characteristic values

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, core-bluetooth

Using the setNotify=YES property I want to create an array populated with the converted 'characteristic.value' values from the below code (Xcode7.2). So far I've only got a null array, all the same values, or only one value at a time

I've implemented

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *voltageArray; //didn't work so 
I deleted and tried the following...
```

The method that I tried to use it in was didUpdateCharacteristic,

```
 if (characteristic.isNotifying)
    {
        NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value 
            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:stringFromData];
        number = @([number floatValue] *5/2034);
        NSLog(@"Characteristic Value: %@", _voltageArray);
    }
```

I also tried the following in the didUpdateValueMethod, along with countless other things,

```
_voltageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self.voltageArray addObject:number];
 NSLog(@"Array: %@", _voltageArray);
```

The best I've gotten is all the same value or all null. How do I get these unsigned voltage values into an array?

**Updated Solution**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *voltageArray;

-(void)peripheral: didUpdateValueForCharacteristic: error:{
if (characteristic.isNotifying)
    {
    if(!self.voltageArray){//Checks if voltageArray has been initialised
    self.voltageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];//If not, initialise the array
}
    // generate characteristic value
    NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    unsigned short baseValue = (unsigned short)stringFromData;
    NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:baseValue];
    number = @([number floatValue] *5/2034);
    NSLog(@"Characteristic Value: %@", number);

    // give potential recording
    self.voltageLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",number];

    // datasource points y-axis
    [_voltageArray addObject:number];
    NSLog(@"Array: %@", _voltageArray);
```

Comment: This is not code that is even compiling.

Comment: It had a warning. Yet it still worked. And It was all essentially copy pasted from my code. If you have any suggestions for making my  I would be grateful. I will try to organize this better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of errors that may be causing your issue.

First:

```
    NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value 
        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:stringFromData];
    number = @([number floatValue] *5/2034);
```

The first method requires a `unsigned short` type as an input, but you are passing a NSString. You could do this instead:

```
NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value 
        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
unsigned short baseValue = (unsigned short)stringFromData.intValue;
float convertedValue = (float)baseValue *5.0/2034.0; //5.0/2034.0 -> so it typecasts the result value as a float, not int
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: convertedValue];
[self.voltageArray addObject:number];
```

Second, it seems that you are initialising your array every time the `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` gets called. Try this instead:

```
-(void)peripheral: didUpdateValueForCharacteristic: error:{
    if (characteristic.isNotifying)
    {
    if(!self.voltageArray){//Checks if voltageArray has been initialised
        self.voltageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];//If not, initialise the array
    }
    NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value 
        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    unsigned short baseValue = (unsigned short)stringFromData.intValue;
    float convertedValue = (float)baseValue *5.0/2034.0;
    NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: convertedValue];
    [self.voltageArray addObject:number];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help with the conversion. That has been giving me some trouble, however, for some reason doing it wrong is the only way I can get it to work.

Comment: Also... the array is still only showing the last value.

Comment: 1) Does the conversion work with the new method? 2) Is the array showing just one object, which is the last object? Or is it showing multiple objects, each the last reading?

Comment: I had to tweak it just a tad bit for my particular use, but it was spot on. I'll post the updated working code modifications just so you can see. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Happy to help! Feel free to accept/upvote answer if your problem was solved.

Comment: Once I have permission.

Comment: You can accept an answer on your own question, if I'm not mistaken, regardless of reputation